# Output Rmarkdown from R notebook

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

I would like to output Rmarkdown from my notebook when I knit it from Rstudio (see below for the reason). I can *almost* get what I want, for example:

````
---
title: "Homework"
output:
  html_document:
    keep_md: true
    md_extensions: +backtick_code_blocks
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval = FALSE, echo = TRUE)
```

Fill the function:

```{r echo=-3}
is_even = function(n) {
  # TODO
  n %% 2 == 0
}

if(is_even(8)) {
  print("correct!")
} else {
  print("wrong!")
}
```
````

The resulting markdown file is *almost* correct:

````
Fill the function:

```r
is_even = function(n) {
  # TODO
}

if(is_even(8)) {
  print("correct!")
} else {
  print("wrong!")
}
```
````

I just need a way to replace the code block preamble from `r` to `{r}`. I could just run `sed`, but I would like to have everything done when knitting from within RStudio, if possible.

Use case: coding assignments. Write a single file with both questions and answers, and strip answers away when knitting, so that I can give the resulting markdown (without answers) to students. They can then open it in Rstudio and fill in what is needed.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I'm with you, but perhaps if you'd like to separate questions from answers you could use sub forms? something like this? https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/ Or are you trying to create a markdown file that outputs markdown files?

Comment: @AmitKohli at the bottom of their post, OP said they want to have a single file. Having children files that compile when the parents do is an underused feature, but it doesn't satisfy their question. They want to create a markdown file that outputs markdown files.

Comment: So I'm still a bit confused. In your code it seems the problem is that the script is outputting `r` rather than `{r}`, but you've not provided any of the code you use to output your rmarkdown, only the markdown output per se. The more interesting problem for me is how to remove the answers programatically... form the examples posted it doesn't look easy or systematic...

Comment: @AmitKohli sorry for not specifying. I knit the notebook from Rstudio, which uses knitr. Including child files could work, but it would make developing the assignments a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it outputs a file with  ```` ```r ```` instead of  ```` ```{r} ```` is because it's a markdown file and not an rmarkdown file, so it's simply the markdown syntaxe that is different.

But, if you open that file in R, you can still run the code, so it,s not really an issue.

Then again, if your goal is to give an Rmarkdown file to your student, where the code block looks like they do in your original file, there's a way.

Either way, you should use the 'md_document' output since, as far as you told us, you won't be using the html file.

Your header should then be :

```
---
output:
  md_document:
    variant: 'markdown+backtick\_code\_blocks'
title: Homework
---
```

which will output an .md file like :

````
---
output:
  md_document:
    variant: 'markdown+backtick\_code\_blocks'
title: Homework
---

Fill the function:

``` {.r}
is_even = function(n) {
  # TODO
}

if(is_even(8)) {
  print("correct!")
} else {
  print("wrong!")
}
```
````

The header now has '{.r}' because it indicates the element has the class r (again it's the md syntaxe)

If you rather have it in .Rmd, you'll need to change the syntaxe to rmd syntaxe. For that, you'll only have to remove the '.' in '{.r}' which can be easily done by adding :

````
```{r eval=TRUE, include=FALSE}
system2("sed", "-e 's/{.r}/{r}/' Homework.md", stdout = 'Homework_out.Rmd')
```
````

You can change the output file name, I named it 'Homework_out.Rmd' because I assumed your original .Rmd was named 'Homework.Rmd'.

The resulting .Rmd will look like :

````
---
output:
  md_document:
    variant: 'markdown+backtick\_code\_blocks'
title: Homework
---

Fill the function:

``` {r}
is_even = function(n) {
  # TODO
}

if(is_even(8)) {
  print("correct!")
} else {
  print("wrong!")
}
```
````